# Como retornar erros de validação de subobjetos, atributos(objetos), listas, para o spring?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, validação, spring-mvc

Hoje eu consigo validar erros de atributos da minha classe que não sejam objetos complexos (outros objetos do meu model que estão relacionados a ele), mas o que ocorre é que o "bean validation" valida os atributos desses objetos, mas, só retorna para o BindingResult os erros de validação dos atributos simples da minha classe (int, Integer, String...), os atributos complexos da minha classe (Endereco, Contato, Documentos...) que possuem outros atributos a serem validados, não estão sendo retornados pelo BindingResult no meu controller, eu sei que eles estão sendo validados corretamente, por que o Hibernate tenta persistir e gera uma exception por não atender aos requisitos da validação.

> Minha classe Modelo Locador:

```
package model;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.validation.constraints.Digits;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import annotations.JSONComponent;

@Entity
public class Locador implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Digits(integer=9, message="O campo código deve ter pelo menos 3 números até 9 números !", fraction = 0)
    @Min(value=1, message="O campo código não pode ter um número menor que 1.")
    @Max(value=999999, message="O campo código pode ser um número entre 1 e 999999.")
    @NotNull(message="O campo código não pode estar vazio !")
    private Long codigo;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Documentos documentos;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Endereco> enderecos;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Contato> contatos;
// outros atributos e omitidos...
```

> Minha classe Modelo Endereco:

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;


@Entity
public class Endereco implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;

        private String logradouro;

        @NotNull(message="O campo número não pode estar vazio !")
        private Integer numero;

//Outros atributos omitidos...
```

> Fiz um teste no meu controlador e percorri todos os erros de
>   validação, mas só aparece os erros de validação dos atributos
>   "simples" da minha classe :

```
   @PostMapping
        public ModelAndView cadastrarLocador(@Valid Locador locador, BindingResult errors, RedirectAttributes redirectAtriAttributes)
                throws Exception {
//aqui varro os erros de validação mas só aparece para mim os referentes ao "código" da minha classe principal....
            if (errors.hasErrors()) {
                errors.getGlobalErrors().forEach(System.out::println);
                errors.getAllErrors().forEach(System.out::println);
                return form();
            }
    //      locadorService.salvar(locador);
            redirectAtriAttributes.addFlashAttribute("locadorCadastrado", locador.getNome());
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/carregar/carregarLocador");
        }

        private ModelAndView form() {
            return new ModelAndView("forward:/carregar/carregarLocador");
        }
```

Comment: Eu consegui um comportamento parecido do que eu queria criando a minha própria validação, mas infelizmente dessa forma eu não consigo mudar a mensagem dependendo do erro de validação.

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tenho uma solução simples para isso. Anote seu atributo como valid. Espero que funcione!

```
@Valid
private Endereco endereco
```